# <meta name="fragment" content="!"> url mapping - how to prevent indexing but allow crawling?

Tags: html, angularjs, seo

I'm working on making my angular js site readable by searchbots. My solution is to serve a static version of the page I want to make readable, instructing the bots to request '/page?_escaped_fragment_=' for the content of '/page' through the 'meta name="fragment" content="!"' tag. My server then reroutes this request to 'page/searchbot' which serves a static version of the page to the bots.

The problem is that I don't want 'page/searchbot' to be indexed, but obviously I do want it to be crawled. I've looked through the specification for the "noindex" value of the robots tag, and can't find anything that explicitly states whether adding this noindex value to '/page/searchbot' will prevent the page I want to index ('/page') from being indexed.

My question is: If I add the "noindex" tag to 'page/searchbot', will the bots still crawl the content, and serve it as content for '/page', correctly indexing '/page', while ignoring 'page/searchbot'?

thanks,

Paul

Comment: "My solution is to serve a static version of the page I want to make readable, instructing the bots to request '/page?_escaped_fragment_=' for the content of '/page' through the tag" — Don't do that. It was an ugly, ugly hack in the first place and Google have now deprecated the approach.

Comment: Make your server return real pages for real URLs and use `pushState` and friends instead of hashbangs.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use pushState, because there is very little ajax in my application. It's just a simple page, which receives updates from users through an ajax PUT. This updates the page model, and updates the page cached html - which relies heavily on angular.

Comment: I'm trying to work out what needs indexing then.

Comment: Well, see the page itself relies heavily on angular variables - basically none of the content is viewable by crawlers, since it needs to respond to user input. When a user commits, the page gets updated (no ajax get requests) - a user can also revert changes. I don't want to serve a static page to users, just to searchbots.

Comment: You can add following meta tag to head of your page to prevent indexing but crawling:
`<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">`. Also `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` has same result.